# Python 'if' statements

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.3, statements

I am doing an assignment where I need to conduct a quiz. This is a part of my code so far.

```
answer = input("Your answer: ")
guessesTaken = 0
points = 0
if answer == 'Call Of Duty' or answer == 'Call of duty' or answer == 'Call of duty' or answer == 'a)' or answer == 'call of duty' or answer == 'a':
    print("You are correct!")
    points = points + 2
    print("You scored two points!")
else: 
    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1
    print("Incorrect!")
    print("You have", guessesTaken, "guess remaining!")
answerb = input("Your answer: ")
if answerb == 'Call Of Duty' or answerb == 'Call of duty' or answerb == 'Call of duty' or answerb == 'a)' or answerb == 'call of duty' or answerb == 'a':
    points = points + 1
    print("You scored one point!")
```

I am getting an error for if answerb. I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. This part of the code is meant to score points for each question you get right. Points system is as follows, 2 for correct answer on first try, 1 on second try and 0 for third try. I thought using answerb would let me have a second try and give 1 point. If you could please explain it to me so I don't do it in the future again. :)

Comment: Please tell us the error message and the location of the error.

Comment: Tell us what is your code intended to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: if answerb == 'Call Of Duty' or answerb == 'Call of duty' or answerb == 'Call of duty' or answerb == 'a)' or answerb == 'call of duty' or answerb == 'a':

Comment: Hint: it would be easier to use `if answer.lower() == 'call of duty'`

Comment: I haven't learned those terms yet nor am I allowed to use them.

Comment: Please provide traceback. If you aren't familiar with the term, traceback means the (complete) error message you get when you program fails.

Comment: builtins.NameError: name 'answerb' is not defined
File "C:\Users\Yavaar Nosimohomed\Desktop\Shahaad quiz 2.py", line 28, in <module>
  if answerb == 'Call Of Duty' or answerb == 'Call of duty' or answerb == 'Call of duty' or answerb == 'a)' or answerb == 'call of duty' or answerb == 'a':

Comment: Is your `answerb = input(…)` line perhaps indented farther than you think it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like minitech suggested, you may have just indented `answerb = input(...)` too far.
I modified your code a little:

```
maxGuesses = 2 #Max number of attempts for the problem
guessesTaken = 0
points = 0
while guessesTaken<maxGuesses:
    answer = input("Your answer: ")
    if answer.lower() == 'call of duty' or answer.lower() == 'a' or answer.lower() == 'a)':
        print("You are correct!")
        points = points + maxGuesses-guessesTaken
        print("You scored %d points!" %(maxGuesses-guessesTaken))
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        print("You have %d guesses remaining!" %(maxGuesses-guessesTaken-1))
        guessesTaken += 1
```

Comment: With this code would the points be attributed as 2 points for guessing the correct answer on first try, 1 point on second try, and 0 for third try or should I add that in myself?

Comment: It would attribute 2 points the first try, 1 the second, and 0 the third.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your comment indicates on line 28 you are checking a variable that has not been set. The matching line in your post appears to be 13. In line 12, you appear to be setting the variable. Maybe try pasting your post back to your editor and re try. The posted code appears to be setting the variable before it attempts to access it correctly.